# Extend filesystem when adding more HDD

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk

What method should I use when I want a filesystem can be extend later ( adding more HDD)?
Can you guy named few method that I should use, and pros/cons of each method?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)).

From Wikipedia:

> LVM is used for the following purposes:
>
> - Creating single logical volumes of multiple physical volumes or entire hard disks (somewhat similar to RAID 0, but more similar to JBOD), allowing for dynamic volume resizing.
> - Managing large hard disk farms by allowing disks to be added and replaced without downtime or service disruption, in combination with hot swapping.
> - On small systems (like a desktop), instead of having to estimate at installation time how big a partition might need to be, LVM allows filesystems to be easily resized as needed.
> - Performing consistent backups by taking snapshots of the logical volumes.
> - Encrypting multiple physical partitions with one password.

Comment: Are there any other method?

Comment: for other methods, you could use `btrfs` or `zfs` as the filesystem - both combine the features of a Volume Manager with a filesystem.   If you're currently using `ext4`, it's fairly easy to convert that to `btrfs` and then add another drive.  Converting `ext4` to `btrfs` is the only method that doesn't require backing up, repartitioning and/or reformatting, then restoring your data - although you should still take a complete backup in case something goes wrong with the conversion.